# Can I get the absolute position of Qwidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have tried several things to get the QWidget's position. What I want is the position of the outer edge of the right Widget (exactly, x location). But I couldn't find a way. Can I get the absolute position of Qwidget?

For debugging, I created a code that returns the position when the mouse is clicked. The result obtained by clicking on the boundary is QPoint(134, 462). I want to get the number 134 without the manual method. Thanks for your help!

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class TestAbsPos(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Can I get an absolute position of qwidget?
        super(TestAbsPos, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(1080, 720)

        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % QtGui.QColor(26, 36, 45).name())

        self.leftWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.rightWidget = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self.rightWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

        window_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(window_layout)

        window_layout.addWidget(self.leftWidget)
        window_layout.addWidget(self.rightWidget)
        window_layout.setStretch(0, 1)
        window_layout.setStretch(1, 8)
        print(self.rightWidget.geometry())
        print(self.leftWidget.geometry())
        print(self.rightWidget.frameGeometry())
        print(self.leftWidget.frameGeometry())
        print(self.rightWidget.pos())
        print(self.leftWidget.pos())
        print(self.rightWidget.x())
        print(self.leftWidget.x())
        print(self.rightWidget.rect().topLeft())
        print(self.rightWidget.rect().topRight())
        print(self.leftWidget.rect().bottomRight())
        print(self.rightWidget.mapToGlobal(self.rightWidget.rect().topLeft()))
        print(self.rightWidget.mapToParent(self.rightWidget.rect().topLeft()))
        print(self.leftWidget.mapToGlobal(self.rightWidget.rect().topLeft()))
        print(self.leftWidget.mapToParent(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dl = TestAbsPos()
    dl.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.closeAllWindows())
```

Comment: What about `QWidget::mapToGlobal()` function?

Comment: You need to wait for the window-manager to map the window to the screen before trying to get the geometry. Move all those `print` statements into a separate method, and then do `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, self.printStuff)`. Alternatively, put `print(self.rightWidget.x())` in `mousePressEvent` to see the relevant value when you click somewhere.

Comment: @ekhumoro, your solution exactly solved my problem. I lacked understanding of Qt behavior. Thank you for helping me!!!